# Panzoom on django with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a really basic django app that displays .png images using django ImageField and ask the user to vote on different choices.
Now I need to make it interactive so that the user can also zoom and pan the images in the form. 
I've downoad this github https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom and followed the instructions in my detail view:  detail.html :

```
<div id="img">
    <img src="{{question.image.url}}"/>
</div>

{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'polls/node_modules/jquery.panzoom/dist/jquery.panzoom.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$("img").panzoom();
$("img").panzoom({ minScale: 0, $zoomRange: $("input[type='range']") });
    });
</script>
```

But nothing happens at all, the image is displayed in a fixed manner. 
Previously I had some issues with 404 errors and now It seems to properly load the .js but It still doesn't work.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have:
1) `<script type="text/javascript" src="_path_to_your_JS_panzoom_file"></script>` - to import that file
2)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $(".panzoom-elements").panzoom();

        // Pass options 
        $("a.panzoom-elements").panzoom({ minScale: 0, $zoomRange: $("input[type='range']") });
        });
</script>
```

OR 2-b) Add those your code to a separate `.js` file and import it at the same way as in paragraph **1**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Actually It still doesn't work and I suspect It to not find the .js. I put the .js in my static folder that is at the same level of my templates folder.

Comment: How does the path to that file look like?

Comment: Well ok this is the problem I think. I can't even load a .css static file.

Comment: do u have `{% load static %}` tag enabled on the top of your template?

Comment: Well ok this is the problem I think. I can't even load a .css static file. I have my index.html which comes with ./templates/templates/index.html and loads the static file directly from ./static/app.js. I use the code : l use  {% load static %} to enter the path like src="{% static jquery.panzoom.js %}". I have in ./mysite/urls.py : urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() added as well so I don't understand...

Comment: show how the `static folder` is configured in your SETTINGS. and better update your question

Comment: Ok I updated the question with my last "progresses". I would be really thankfull If you could look at It again

Comment: Is load static placed on the beginning of html file?

Comment: And I still does not see your settings.py file

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally I found the problem. The documentation is probably done for people who have a bit more background in that field! But of course other imports are required to make it work:

```
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'polls/node_modules/jquery.panzoom/test/libs/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'polls/node_modules/jquery.panzoom/dist/jquery.panzoom.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'polls/node_modules/jquery.panzoom/test/libs/jquery.mousewheel.js' %}"></script>

<section>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="panzoom">
      <img src="{{question.image.url}}">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="zoom-in">Zoom In</button>
    <button class="zoom-out">Zoom Out</button>
    <input type="range" class="zoom-range">
    <button class="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var $section = $('section').first();
      $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom({
        $zoomIn: $section.find(".zoom-in"),
        $zoomOut: $section.find(".zoom-out"),
        $zoomRange: $section.find(".zoom-range"),
        $reset: $section.find(".reset")
      });
    })();
  </script>
</section>
```